# Adding textbox inside dropdown list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, textbox

I am trying to add a textbox inside my dropdown menu but everytime i click the textbox inside of it the dropdown closes. Is there a way that i can use the textbox without the dropdown closing ? thank you. I have using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code somewhere of body to stop closing:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').find('form').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   });
```

Comment: @LensAlexis No problem. if this answer works you can accept it so it can help other with the same question